# What is the return value of @@ProcId in an ad-hoc SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I've been looking at logging procedure executions on our reporting database to a table, and aim to come up with a generic snippet of code that can be copied into any proc we want to log.

The above lead me to play around with @@ProcID. [The Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/procid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) explains that this will provide the object ID of the proc, udf, or trigger within which it is contained. That makes sense, but I'm also seeing it return a value when run directly from a new query window. I've not been able to relate this integer to an object id in the database - I have no idea what this Id represents. I'm sysadmin on the server I'm trying this on so there shouldn't be any permission restrictions.

I haven't managed to find anything online about this - the only [search result](https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/preview/en/2351066) which looked relevant  is on a login restricted SAP support forum.

```
Use Master

select @@procid -- returns an integer
select object_name(@@procid) -- NULL
select * from sys.objects where object_id = @@ProcId -- 0 rows
```

Comment: What's neat about this is that `use master; select @@procid` will also return a different result than having the two commands on separate lines, but it will also be the same value every time you run it.  Also, the number of blank lines between `use master` and `select @@procid` changes the result.

Comment: It isn't documented; since it remains constant with the query text and does not vary by server when no objects are accessed it is most likely a value derived from the plan hash of the adhoc query, though there appears to be no obvious direct relation to values in the system views (like `query_plan_hash`).

Comment: Ah, there we go. This value corresponds to the `objectid` value of the query plan as returned by `sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes`, which in turn documents "for plans of type "Adhoc" or "Prepared", it is an internal hash of the batch text". Using it for logging is precarious since this value only remains available for as long as the query plan is actually available. (Try `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans p CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p.plan_handle) t CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(p.plan_handle) a  WHERE a.attribute = 'objectid' AND a.value = @@PROCID`.)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense - thanks. I didn't intend to use the ad-hoc value for anything, but I was suprised by its behaviour and didn't want to move forward before getting to the bottom of it. Ill happily mark as the answer if you post below.

Comment: I believe I would reframe Jeroen's answer slightly.  If the value returned is the hash of the "batch" text, then it might or might not be cached.   If not cached, we see the behavior @LittleBobbyTables  describes, where changes to the text change the value of @@PROCID but nothing more can be queried.  If the hash value IS cached, we get Jeroen's answer and can do the self-referential query.  It too me a few minutes to think it through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this isn't documented, the value corresponds to the `objectid` attribute of the cached query plan, as returned by `sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes`. The meaning of that *is* [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-plan-attributes-transact-sql): "For plans of type "Adhoc" or "Prepared", it is an internal hash of the batch text."

To confirm, the following query returns the text of the query itself (and thus serves as a form of [quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29) for SQL Server, albeit one that cheats as it inspects runtime values):

```
SELECT t.[text] 
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans p 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p.plan_handle) t 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(p.plan_handle) a 
WHERE a.attribute = 'objectid' AND a.value = @@PROCID
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what tool you are using to submit the command. Many tools will create a temporary stored procedure containing your commands (using ODBC prepared statement for example), and then run that procedure.

Speculating, it may be that the tool is detecting that the statement is unchanged and therefore re-using the previous prepared statement. In this case SQL server would not be involved, it would be the client library.

Alternatively, it may be that the server is detecting the sql is unchanged, and the preserved procid is a consequence of query-plan caching system. (SQL server attempts to detect repeated ad-hoc statements and optimise by re-using the plans for them.)

Either way you should consider this a curiosity, not something you should rely on for correct operation of your system as it may well change with updates to SQL Server or your client library.

Comment: I was running the query directly from SSMS, so it sounds like it is the plan cache